# Why eshell lists my host environment variables when I am connected to other machine via ssh?

Tags: eshell, ssh

I am connected to another machine using `tramp` and my `eshell` does send all the commands to remote machine but when I do `echo $PATH` it prints me my local `PATH`. Why?

Comment: Because `eshell` is not a shell running on that remote machine?

Comment: If you *need* a shell running on the remote machine, then don't use `eshell`.  Use `shell`, or run a shell inside `term`, or similar.

Comment: @phils, Absolutely. What then `eshell`s ssh support actually offers? Mixture of host's and remote's shells? How do I distinguish what I am running when I use `eshell`? Why do we have ssh support in `eshell`? Now I use ansi-term.

Comment: Why? Because having that support is notably better than not having it. And of course there's nothing stopping you from running `ssh <hostname>` from eshell (but at that point I think one of the other options is more sensible).  `eshell` is a native elisp shell; there's no "mixture of host's and remote's shell" happening.

Comment: When you open `Dired` using `Tramp`, which is Emacs way to do ssh (and others) and then open `Eshell` from there, you get a shell that runs binaries from the remote machine but at the same time prints host machine's `PATH` when you perform `echo $PATH`. That is inconsistent and misleading. A message that states "Eshell does not support ssh connection" would be more helpful than having an inconsistent shell.

Comment: It's not inconsistent if you understand that `eshell` is running locally inside Emacs.  You could similarly mount a remote filesystem via sshfs and run remote binaries on that filesystem in any kind of local shell, and you wouldn't think it strange that your environment was still local.

Comment: @phils At first I also thought that this would be related to eshell not running on the remote host. But then I found the comment `Content of $PATH. It might be different from \(getenv \"PATH\"), when
'default-directory' points to a remote host.` of `eshell-path-env`. The variable `eshell-path-env` is actually set by `tramp-eshell-directory-change` if `default-directory` is a `tramp-tramp-file-name-p`.

Comment: @foki What is the value of `default-directory` in your Eshell buffer? What does `M-: (tramp-tramp-file-name-p default-directory)` return when called from that buffer?

Comment: @Tobias, oh interesting!

Comment: @Tobias my `default-directory` is `/ssh:foki@remotemachine:/home/foki/`. My `(tramp-tramp-file-p default-directory)` is `t`.

Comment: @phils You are probably right for the example of mounting a remote file system, but I am describing this specific case in which it is misleading. A layman like me expects a remote shell when `ssh` to a remote machine or a message that it is not supported and certainly not a mixture of these two.